# neo4j query for a node using python rest client

Tags: python, nosql, neo4j

I have nodes in index with following proprties:

```
{'user_id': u'00050714572570434939', 'hosts': [u'http://shyjive.blogspot.com/'], 'follows': ['null']}
```

Now i have index and I am trying simple query to index to get nodes as :

```
index = gdb.nodes.indexes.create('blogger2')
uid = gdb.nodes.create()
uid["hosts"] = ['http://shyjive.blogspot.com/']
uid["user_id"] = "00050714572570434939"
uid["follows"] = ['null']
print index["user_id"]["00050714572570434939"][:]
```

this **returns []** , what is wrong here !!

reason why i am using list in python as suggested by developers on neo4j groups is I want to store multi property values to the node , so instead of array i am using list here

Answer (score 1):

You first need to index the node. If you are not using [automatic indexing](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-configurable-auto-indexes.html), the code for [neo4j-rest-client](https://neo4j-rest-client.readthedocs.org/en/latest/indices.html) would be:

```
index["user_id"]["00050714572570434939"] = uid
```

Now you have:

```
>>> index["user_id"]["00050714572570434939"][:]
[<Neo4j Node: http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/38>]
```

Comment: Thanks for your time but when I try to index list because I want to add multiple value to a property of node for eg:
 uid = gdb.nodes.create()

 index["user_id"][x] = uid

 index["hosts"][source] = uid
 index["follows"][dest] = uid
above source and dest are list so it gives me error:

    tx = tx or value[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not support yet for list as index key. But it's coming!